# Check before to insert record into Database Table

Tags: mysql

I have a problem with inserting data into the database table using CRON script that is executing every day.

So, I am using that script to insert orders into order tables that have `Order ID` and `Order number` as keys.
But in the code, I am generating `ID` of order dynamically and `article number` is for each order incrementing for one.
But, with this solution, I cannot add check in my SQL query (`IF NOT EXIST...`), so orders will be duplicated all the time...And I don't have an idea at the moment for some smart solution...

Could someone provide me any suggestion for the problem?
Thank you.

Comment: I see words for *CRON script*, *code*, *script* but no actual code or script. Please post such code and tag the language: Python? PHP? SQL?

Comment: "so orders will be duplicated all the time", how so?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` Syntax.
[Here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) you can find more information on how to use it.
Hope this will help you

Comment: That is my main problem. 
I will never have Duplicate Key and for that, I cannot add a check...